# enabling layout disables cjuidatepicker yii

Tags: yii

I have a small view which renders cjuidatepicker widget.

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'flat'=>FALSE,
            //  'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'start_date',
        //  'value' => $model->start_date,
                'name'=>'dateSelect',
            'options' => array(
                'showButtonPanel' => true,
                'changeYear' => true,
                'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                ),
            ));?>
```

while this renders nicely without using a layout, but when I put this view in my project layout, the datepicker refuses to show up.
I have no ideas where to look for this, all the css and js are loading similarly in layout and without layout.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: May be some jquery version issue

Comment: the div created without the layout <div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div> does not get created when the widget is called from within the layout.

Comment: Ya that only the jquery plugin is not creating this div check the versions used

Comment: can u post your layout file ?

Comment: its too big for the comments section, can I upload it somewhere? Thanks

Comment: http://www.sendspace.com/file/40pevt the layout file

Comment: Ok if you want to check which jquery version is overlapping try commenting the scripts in your layout file and then try

Comment: check for the console , are you getting any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple versions of jquery being loaded and that created quite a mess. Yii jquery was different from the template jquery version being used.  Brought both of them to an agreement and boom!!

Answer (score 0):

Having dealt my fair share with the datepicker, I'm willing to bet money on that the root to your problem is an error in your javascript. Try to comment out all included javascript in your layout and see what happens. For example, maybe you have jQuery included twice, or some code section missing a closing bracket. Basically any js error will throw datepicker off it's game. Just check the js console in your favorite browser.